# Why text gets cutoff in Text in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

As you can see from the image below the `L` (Lorem) and the `p` (previewing) are cutoff, any idea why some of the text inside the `Text` gets cut off?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image("placeholder-image")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .ignoresSafeArea()

            VStack {
                Text("Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups..")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.systemGray)
                    .cornerRadius(15)

                Button("Tap Me") {
                    // some action
                }.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            }
            .padding()
            .background(.thinMaterial)
            .cornerRadius(15)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cornerRadius` adds clipping, so remove it after text (anyway it is not needed there by logic of your code even if it would behave differently)

```
VStack {
    Text("Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups..")
        .foregroundColor(Color.systemGray)
        //.cornerRadius(15)                  // << this !!
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use as below for text:

```
  .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
```

Comment: Unfortunately adding `.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)` to the `Text` view didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: you can give ```VStack``` with ```.frame(width: 200)```.